# node-webkit running a function from external source

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am loading a remote page with an iframe in node-webkit app.
I would like to run  a function from the node.js app from the webpage.

In app.js i have

```
var xxx = function(){ console.log('test'); }
```

and in http://www.test.com/index.html i have tried:

```
window.xxx();
xxx();
global.xxx();
```

But nothing seems to work.

How can i do that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to access a function that's defined in the remote page that you are including as an iframe in your current page, right?

There are two separate issue here, I think.

First, you need to have a handle on the iframe, then access that window's environment through the 'contentWindow' property of the iframe dom element, i.e. given an iframe with id `foo`, that points to a page with a function named `bar`, you could do this:

```
x = document.getElementById('foo');
x.bar();
```

This works fine for me with a local page, but the other issue is that you might find some difficulty with running a remote page in an iframe and still having access.  If it's a page under your control, that might work, but some pages don't like to be run in iframes, so then you have to sandbox to some extent, which may interfere with your ability to access it in this way.  It's been a while since I played with sandboxing, so I'm not sure, but if it's a page you control, you should be able to set it up so it's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The page is under my control and i want to run a node.js function from the remote page, not to run a function on the remote page.